# CordovaWebView inside a Fragment returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, cordova-2.0.0

I'm trying to implement the CordovaWebView (2.2.0) inside a fragment but it's returning an error when trying to inflate the layout.

My xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id = "@+id/mainView"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

My onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cordovawebview, container); // <--- the error occurs here!

    return v;
}
```

Error:

> 10-25 15:52:02.839: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2878): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
>   NullPointerException CordovaWebView.java line 691

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("config", "xml", this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName());
```

It seems that the resource is null here.

I have already checked it and the config.xml file is in the xml folder.

I can implement it in a FragmentActivity but I need it in a Fragment.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cordovawebview, container, false); // <--- add false parameter
    CordovaWebView webView = (CordovaWebView)v.findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CordovaWebViews need to be created on the activity the fragment is on as well as the fragment itself. You can create your own ContextWrapper and supply it to your inflater to handle doing this for you.

Here is a step by step guide on how to do just that: https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/app-sample-android-phonegap/wiki/Embed-Webview-in-Android-Fragment